# asp.net core route handle id after domain

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

How can I handle this in the ASP.NET Core route `http://example.com/id`?

Basically, I need to be able to format some URL with some kind of id right after the domain (please notice this is not /Home/Index).

So assuming I want to display an image with `id=1` when you visit the url: `http://example.com/1` or `http://example.com?id=1` where can I put my logic? How can I handle this route?

Comment: The same way you make any other route.  What don't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [basic routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing), and the docs answer for you how to do this.

To strictly handle `http://example.com/{id}`, you need to define a default controller (typically HomeController), and define a route that matches the id.
Inside HomeController would be an action that looks something like

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public void GetImage(string id) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can set up routing without using attributes that would account for grabbing the ID (which, again, the docs answers for you!).

Answer (score 0):

For MVC5 you can add a new route for example
**and make it before the default route**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "custom",
    url: "{Id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "controller-name", action = "action-name"}
);
```